# Drag and Drop an object on an image and get location

Tags: jquery, silverlight, drag-and-drop

I'll be starting a new project and I need some help from experienced developers to prevent upcoming problems with the technology.

I'll be doing a website which will include image drag and drop on top of another image and get relative position of the moved object (startx,starty,endx,endy).

For such a task, I'm in between JQuery and Silverlight.

Which one would you go with? I have no experience with any of the languages but I know c#, asp.net have done some Jquery but not enough to make my mind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery**, use the [jQuery UI Draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). This is also quite easy to do in silverlight, but if it can be done without the need of a proprietary plugin, do it. Even I am throwing away 3 years of silverlight knowledge for javascript and html5.

So, here is the jQuery code to get start and stop position for the *Draggable* plugin:

```
$("#dragger").draggable({
start: function(event, ui) {
    var start = $(this).position();
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    var stop = $(this).position();
}
});
```

X and Y can be accessed as follows: `position().Left()` or `position().Top()`

Answer (score 2):

For the client site part i would prefer [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)…

It's rock solid. Great performance and an awseome community (future proof). Not to forget with great documentation.……